# Azure function to query specific dates in Azure Table via node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, odata, azure-table-storage

For some reason the code below in Azure nodejs via odata does not return any data in the array. An example date format should be like **2023-06-29T08:38:27.92Z**

What I want to get is to get those dates 1 and 30 days in the future

```
const response30Days = await client.listEntities({
            queryOptions: { filter: odata`expirationDate eq datetimeoffset'${getFutureDate(30).toISOString()}'` }
        });
        const entities30Days = response30Days.items || [];

        const response1Day = await client.listEntities({
            queryOptions: { filter: odata`expirationDate eq datetimeoffset'${getFutureDate(1).toISOString()}'` }
        });
        const entities1Day = response1Day.items || [];
        
        context.log("Entities with expirationDate exactly 30 days in the future:");
        entities30Days.forEach(entity => {
            context.log(`PartitionKey: ${entity.partitionKey}, RowKey: ${entity.rowKey}, Entity: ${JSON.stringify(entity)}`);
        });

        context.log("Entities with expirationDate exactly 1 day in the future:");
        entities1Day.forEach(entity => {
            context.log(`PartitionKey: ${entity.partitionKey}, RowKey: ${entity.rowKey}, Entity: ${JSON.stringify(entity)}`);
        });



function getFutureDate(days) {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I created an entity for 1 day in the future of the table storage in the Azure portal as below,

[image]

And, I created another entity for 30 days in the future of the table storage in the Azure portal as below,

[image]

***I tried below Azure Functions node js code to get the table storage entities for 1 day and 30 days in the future.***

**Code:**

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  const { TableServiceClient, AzureNamedKeyCredential, TableClient } = require("@azure/data-tables");

  const account = "<storage-account-name>";
  const accountKey = "<account-key>";
  const connestring = "<connec-string>";
  const tableName = "<table-name>";

  const credential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
  const serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(`https://<storage-account-name>.table.core.windows.net`, credential);

  try {
    const futureExpirationDates = await getFutureExpirationDates();
    context.res = { body: futureExpirationDates };
  } catch (error) {
    context.res = { status: 500, body: "An error occurred: " + error.message };
  }

  async function getFutureExpirationDates() {
    const partitionKey = "key";

    const tableClient = new TableClient(`https://<storage-account-name>.table.core.windows.net`, tableName, credential);

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const oneDayFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
    const thirtyDaysFromNow = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 

    const queryOptions = {
      queryOptions: {
        filter: `expirationDate eq datetime'${oneDayFromNow.toISOString()}' or expirationDate eq datetime'${thirtyDaysFromNow.toISOString()}'`
      }
    };

    const entities = [oneDayFromNow, thirtyDaysFromNow];
    for await (const entity of tableClient.listEntities(queryOptions)) {
      entities.push(entity.expirationDate);
    }

    return entities;
  }
};
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

***With the above output URL, I got the expirationDate for 1 day and 30 days in the future at browser as below,***

[image]